# Is it possible to convert android/iOS app in cross platform app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is it possible to convert an android/iOS app in a cross platform app like react native or flutter?

I had an app developed in android and iOS and I want to convert it to, for example, react native so that I can continue developing it myself because I have no skills in android/iOS but I have skills in React Native and Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bro. Actually there is no way to do that
You must rewrite the app form the scratch using your new cross platform framework